# How to play a tone using Xamarin on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I would like my Xamarin-based iPhone app to play a custom tone but I'm new to iOS development and am struggling to find a simple way to do so.

Ultimately I'd like to be able to make a metal detector type of sound, where infrequent beeps become more frequent and eventually continuous but, to get started, a simple sine wave will suffice.

I've found the objectal-monotouch library (https://github.com/tescott/objectal-monotouch) and an example project in Objective-C (http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) but the former has out-dated references to monotouch and the latter is quite a bit of code to convert for a non-Objective-C programmer.

Before I set off on either of these paths, can anyone recommend any sample code or an up-to-date library to achieve this more simply?

Many thanks,

Richard

**Edit:** I went ahead and ported the cocoawithlove example. Please contact me if it's of interest. It wasn't rocket science, but it wasn't trivial either, due to significant differences in the Xamarin API. If anyone knows of any resources to aid such conversions (e.g. mappings from the native API to Xamarin or better Xamarin docs!) please let me know!

Comment: Is there any chance that you can share the converted code? I know it is a year later but this is the internet :)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSUrl soundURL = NSUrl.FromFilename(soundfile);

using (AVAudioPlayer player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(soundURL)) {
    player.Volume = 1.0f;
    player.PrepareToPlay();
    player.Play();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: It's really straight forward - no explanation needed, if you need one - get back to the 101's of development.

Comment: Here are two good references for playing a sound in Xamarin.iOS: 
[Xamarin - Playing Sound with AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer/) **and** [Apple's AVAudioPlayer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer)